# How to copy an email.message.Message object?

Tags: python, email

I have an email message obtained via Python's `email.parser` module:

```
parser = email.parser.Parser()
msg1 = parser.parse(sys.stdin)
```

I would like to create a copy of this object, but I'm not sure how best to go about that.  I can use the `copy` module...

```
msg2 = copy.deepcopy(msg1)
```

...but given that a MIME message may contain a somewhat arbitrary tree of parts I'm not sure if this is the right solution or not.  I could serialize and reparse the message...

```
msg2 = parser.parse(msg1.as_string())
```

...but the documentation suggests that the `as_string` method may not always do the right thing.  I can create a `StringIO` object and use a `generator`...

```
buf = String()
g = email.generator.Generator(buf)
g.flatten(msg1)
msg2 = parser.parse(buf.getvalue())
```

...but that seems like an awful lot of work to copy something that's already been parsed once.

Using the `copy` module seems like the simplest solution, but I'm unfamiliar with the `copy` module.  Am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a MIME message, you may be able to assume that no matter how nested an attribute may be, there will be an end.  If so, deepcopy should do a recursive copy on every attribute of the message, so you will end up with the right thing doing copy.deepcopy.